# Which of these places in Papua New Guinea or the Solomon Islands would be the most accessible?

Tags: budget, oceania, eclipses, papua-new-guinea

There's a solar eclipse on May 10 that covers part of Papua New Guinea.  There are four feasible options to see it, as far as I can tell from [the path](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~jander/ase2013/solomons.png).

- Alotau, on the east of Papua New Guinea.
- Normanby Island
- Muyua Island
- or possibly, Vurango Island in the Solomon Islands

I'm trying to establish which would be the least effort to get to.  My friend in Port Moresby tells me that I'd likely need a boat to get to Normanby.  I figure I'd ask here.  **Which of these is the most accessible location, in terms of cash spent?** (I don't mind any form of transportation, although I hesitate to hitch in this territory).  As you can tell, I know very little about the region.

Comment: I've been to PNG a number of times but never to the Solomons. Re. PNG, it's a beautiful but dangerous place. That being said, I managed to spend a weekend at [Loloata](http://www.loloata.com) where everything was brilliant - a little primitive, but it was fine. As it's a little island, it has dark skies and could be a great place to watch the eclipse.

Comment: That depends of course on where you start the travel.

Comment: @gerrit, from outside PNG.

Comment: @DavidDelMonte Thanks, but I don't believe this is actually an answer.  Lolota isn't any of the places I've mentioned.  In addition, a quick check shows it isn't in the path for the eclipse either.  I've moved your answer to a comment instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after talking to a friend in Port Moresby, it appears that:

- Alotau has daily flights from Port Moresby with [Air Niugini](http://www.airniugini.com.pg/) or [Airlines PNG](http://www.apng.com)
- Normandy Island, he reckons you may have to charter a boat from Alotau which defeats the point of accessibility
- Solomon Islands also fly from Port Moresby with [Air Niugini](http://www.airniugini.com.pg/).

Conclusion: Alotau appears to be the one to go for, in terms of both accessibility and price.